# vanilla js eventListener on navigation

Tags: javascript

I have built a "mega menu" that is working, but I would appreciate some advice on how my javascript can be improved.

**Step 1** is looping through the top level menu items and applying the correct megamenu class names where necessary:

```
const megamenu = document.getElementById('megamenu');
let megamenuChildren = megamenu.children;
let megamenuChildrenArray = Array.from(megamenuChildren);

for (let i = 0; i < megamenuChildrenArray.length; i++) {

    let sub = megamenuChildrenArray[i].children;

    // if the nav li contains x1 children it is a regular link
    // if the nav li contains x2 children it is a megamenu item and we add the classes

    if (sub.length === 2) {

        let subArray = Array.from(sub);
        subArray[0].classList.add('megamenu-trigger-' + i);
        subArray[1].classList.add('megamenu-sub-' + i);

    }
}
```

**Step 2** Earlier in my development I learned that we shouldn't add eventListener inside a loop! So instead I am adding an eventListener to the document to listen for all clicks.

There are only ever a maximum of x5 li's in the top level menu, so I am checking each one for a click and swapping the class `'dn'` (display: none;) for `'db'` (display: block;). I am also adding the class `'megamenu-sub-triggered'`:

```
document.addEventListener('click', function(event) {

    if (event.target.matches('.megamenu-trigger-0')) {
        console.log('trigger 0 clicked!');
        event.preventDefault();
        let subZero = document.getElementsByClassName('megamenu-sub-0')[0];
        subZero.classList.remove('dn');
        subZero.classList.add('db', 'megamenu-sub-triggered');
    }

    if (event.target.matches('.megamenu-trigger-1')) {
        console.log('trigger 1 clicked!');
        event.preventDefault();
        let subOne = document.getElementsByClassName('megamenu-sub-1')[0];
        subOne.classList.remove('dn');
        subOne.classList.add('db', 'megamenu-sub-triggered');
    }

    if (event.target.matches('.megamenu-trigger-2')) {
        console.log('trigger 2 clicked!');
        event.preventDefault();
        let subTwo = document.getElementsByClassName('megamenu-sub-2')[0];
        subTwo.classList.remove('dn');
        subTwo.classList.add('db', 'megamenu-sub-triggered');
    }

    if (event.target.matches('.megamenu-trigger-3')) {
        console.log('trigger 3 clicked!');
        event.preventDefault();
        let subThree = document.getElementsByClassName('megamenu-sub-3')[0];
        subThree.classList.remove('dn');
        subThree.classList.add('db', 'megamenu-sub-triggered');
    }

    if (event.target.matches('.megamenu-trigger-4')) {
        console.log('trigger 4 clicked!');
        event.preventDefault();
        let subFour = document.getElementsByClassName('megamenu-sub-4')[0];
        subFour.classList.remove('dn');
        subFour.classList.add('db', 'megamenu-sub-triggered');
    }
}
```

**Step 3** Finally, **inside the same document.addEventListener above**, I am listening for clicks outside of the `'.megamenu-sub-triggered'` element, and checking each possible megamenu to see (a) if it exists, and (b) if it contains the triggered class.

If conditions (a) and (b) are met, I am putting the classes back to their original state:

```
if (document.getElementsByClassName('megamenu-sub-triggered')) {
    if (!event.target.closest('.megamenu-sub-triggered')) {

        var subZero = document.getElementsByClassName('megamenu-sub-0')[0];
        if (subZero && subZero.matches('.megamenu-sub-0.megamenu-sub-triggered')) {
            subZero.classList.remove('db', 'megamenu-sub-triggered');
            subZero.classList.add('dn');
        }

        var subOne = document.getElementsByClassName('megamenu-sub-1')[0];
        if (subOne && subOne.matches('.megamenu-sub-1.megamenu-sub-triggered')) {
            subOne.classList.remove('db', 'megamenu-sub-triggered');
            subOne.classList.add('dn');
        }

        var subTwo = document.getElementsByClassName('megamenu-sub-2')[0];
        if (subTwo && subTwo.matches('.megamenu-sub-2.megamenu-sub-triggered')) {
            subTwo.classList.remove('db', 'megamenu-sub-triggered');
            subTwo.classList.add('dn');
        }

        var subThree = document.getElementsByClassName('megamenu-sub-3')[0];
        if (subThree && subThree.matches('.megamenu-sub-3.megamenu-sub-triggered')) {
            subThree.classList.remove('db', 'megamenu-sub-triggered');
            subThree.classList.add('dn');
        }

        var subFour = document.getElementsByClassName('megamenu-sub-4')[0];
        if (subFour && subFour.matches('.megamenu-sub-4.megamenu-sub-triggered')) {
            subFour.classList.remove('db', 'megamenu-sub-triggered');
            subFour.classList.add('dn');
        }
    }
}
```

Any help improving this code, and my own javascript knowledge, is very much appreciated!

Many thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Step 1

**Concise iteration and selectors**

`.children` returns an array-like collection of elements. While the collection isn't actually an array, it still has elements at numeric indicies and has a `.length`. So, there's no need to convert it into an actual array first if you're iterating over it with a `for (let i = 0; i < collection.length; ...)` loop. So, with:

```
let megamenuChildren = megamenu.children;
let megamenuChildrenArray = Array.from(megamenuChildren);
for (let i = 0; i < megamenuChildrenArray.length; i++) {
```

you can instead use:

```
let megamenuChildren = megamenu.children;
for (let i = 0; i < megamenuChildren.length; i++) {
```

*But there's a better option*. Since you don't really care about the *index* being iterated over, you just care about the *elements* in the collection, how about iterating through only the elements, instead of the indicies? Use `for..of` instead:

```
for (const child of megamenuChildren) {
```

*But there's a better option*. Rather than selecting the `#megamenu` element, and then using `.children` to get to its children, then iterating over the children, you can use a [selector string instead](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors) to get to the children immediately:

```
for (const child of document.querySelectorAll('#megamenu > *')) {
```

The selector sting `#megamenu > *` means: select all children of elements with an ID of `megamenu`.

*But there's a better option*. You could add these classes to the HTML instead of through the JS, or you could not add these classes or anything like them at all - see below, at the bottom of Step 2.

**Checking children length is weird** Once the children are selected, doing this:

```
// if the nav li contains x1 children it is a regular link
// if the nav li contains x2 children it is a megamenu item and we add the classes

if (sub.length === 2) {
```

is pretty strange. I think it would be much more natural for the parent elements to distinguish *themselves* by whether they're a container for more items or just contain a plain link. Maybe use a class name of `subgroup` for such parents. Then, rather than checking the length of the children, you could just change the selector string above to:

```
for (const child of document.querySelectorAll('#megamenu > .subgroup')) {
```

in order to iterate over the subgroups.

#### Step 2

> Earlier in my development I learned that we shouldn't add eventListener inside a loop!

**Listeners in a loop are just fine** as long as you use modern syntax, usually. There is only *one* situation where adding listeners in a loop will fundamentally fail, which is if you're using `var`, which has unintuitive function scope instead of block scope:

```
// Bad:
for (var i = 0; i < elms.length; i++) {
  var elm = elms[i];
  elm.addEventListener('click', () => {
    console.log(elm, 'clicked');
  });
}
```

```
// Fix:
for (let i = 0 // ...
```

One should never be using `var` in source code anyway, nowadays, due in part to problems like this. Always use `const` or `let` instead. (Prefer `const` when possible, since it indicates reassignment will not occur.)

There is one situation in which adding listeners inside a loop can lead to difficult-to-manage code, which is if elements that need listeners are added *dynamically*. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements. In such a case, it's often more manageable to add a single listener to the parent instead of adding listeners to the children *on pageload* and adding listeners to each *dynamically created* child on creation.

But your situation does not fall into either of the above 2 categories. There's nothing wrong with adding lots of listeners (except, maybe, if you have 1000+ of them, or something like that - that might have a performance impact, I'm not sure). If you can change your Step 2 code so that it adds listeners in a loop instead of the repetitive `if (event.target.matches('.megamenu-trigger-1')) {` blocks, feel free to do that. Or, you could continue on with your event delegation approach, but with some improvements:

**Use querySelector to select a single element** instead of `getElementsByClassName(..)[0]`. For example, you can replace these:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('megamenu-sub-1')[0]
```

with

```
document.querySelector('.megamenu-sub-1')
```

Another benefit of `querySelector` is that it accepts a selector string, and selector strings are far more flexible than plain classes are tag names.

Or, rather than all of these classes, you could **navigate from the clicked element instead**. You could remove Step 1's code completely, only keeping the `subgroup` class name for menu parents. Then, on click, check to see if the target is the first child of a `.subgroup` - if it is, this is the equivalent of the `trigger` being clicked, so you can dynamically navigate to its next sibling and change its class. Replace *all* of Step 2's code with the following:

```
document.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  const { target } = e;
  if (!target.matches('.subgroup > :first-child')) {
    return;
  }
  // A trigger element was clicked, so:
  e.preventDefault();
  const submenu = target.nextElementSibling;
  submenu.classList.remove('dn');
  submenu.classList.add('db', 'megamenu-sub-triggered');
});
```

The most important part is using `.nextElementSibling` to get to the clicked element's next sibling, instead of using all those classes.

#### Step 3

**Collections are truthy**. You have `if (document.getElementsByClassName('megamenu-sub-triggered')) {`, but `getElementsByClassName` returns a collection, and not a possibly falsey value, so the `if` check is redundant. If you want to check if any elements match the class, check the collection's `length >= 1` instead. Or, even better...

**Iteration is overkill.** Instead, you can select the currently opened submenu element which has the `db` class with a single selector string. If it exists, and if the clicked element was not inside it, then reset its classes:

```
document.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  const openSubmenu = document.querySelector('megamenu-sub-triggered');
  if (openSubmenu && !openSubmenu.contains(event.target)) {
    openSubmenu.classList.remove('db', 'megamenu-sub-triggered');
    openSubmenu.classList.add('dn');
  }
});
```

**Multiple classes?** It's odd to have 3 separate classes that get added or removed together. It would make more sense to change your CSS rules so that you can have just a *single* class instead, that gets toggled on or off. For example, you could have a `submenu-open` class, and then do:

```
submenu.classList.add('submenu-open');
```

or

```
openSubmenu.classList.remove('submenu-open');
```

without the classes of `db`, `megamenu-sub-triggered`, or `dn` at all.